# Ruby - Rails 4 - Pundit - Policy and authorization error for a route #index_fr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, authorization, policy, pundit

Sorry, I didn't see another place to ask a question about Pundit... Thank you for your help.

I am working on a Ruby on rails API and I would like to create an url (.../api/v1/attractions/fr) list some information about one of my models. But I've got this error message from Pundit :

> Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError at /api/v1/attractions/fr
>   Api::V1::AttractionsController

and this error for verify_authorized in the lib/pundit.rb file

```
def verify_authorized
    raise AuthorizationNotPerformedError, self.class unless pundit_policy_authorized?
end
```

This is my configuration :

```
# app/config/routes.rb

namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :lines, only: [ :index, :show ] do
        collection do
          get '/fr', to: 'attractions#index_fr'
        end
      end
   end
end

# app/controllers/api/v1/attractions_controller.rb

class Api::V1::AttractionsController < Api::V1::BaseController
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @attractions = policy_scope(Attraction)
    @attractions = Attraction.all
  end

  def index_fr
    @attractions = policy_scope(Attraction)
    @attractions = Attraction.all
  end
end

# app/policies/application_policy.rb

class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def index_fr?
    false
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `before_filter :skip_authorization` to your api controller.

However the pundit `verify_authorized` method should only be called if you've added it as an `after_action`.